# Get power consumption on iMac

Tags: swift, shell

I want to read out and log my iMacs power consumption. Anybody has an idea how I can do that.

Swift, Shell or Ruby would be great!

Thanks a lot,
André

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're talking about a non-laptop that doesn't use a battery, so there isn't nearly as much useful power usage information available as you might be able to get for a laptop that does use a battery.

But either way, if this were my problem I'd start writing a Swift app or a command line tool that incorporates the IOKit framework, which has a few header files with useful information, such as [IOPowerSources.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOPowerSources_header_reference/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011509-CHIOPowerSourceshFunctions-DontLinkElementID_3) and [IOPSKeys.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOPSKeys_header_reference/).

More detail can be seen in the ["Hardware Access Options" section of this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_Other_APIs/AH_Other_APIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000377-TPXREF104).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have some problems getting started with this. I have never worked with a .h file before. I imported IOKit into my Swift file but then I don't know how to proceed. You could give me a hint? Or some source where I can find an answer, on how I get a value out of the .h file?